# Django-App s3 bucket not working properly

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

So I'm currently deploying my website on heroku and I want to serve the static and media files from AWS S3, and at this point the files are being served from aws but the styling is not being applied.

[image]

This are my settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl' : 'max-age=86400'}
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-3'

# AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4's3

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "joaoLina.storages.MediaStorage"
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/'
```

I have the right permissions on my bucket and as you can se the files are being served from aws:
[image]

So if someone knows what I'm missing I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was I did not have my cors policy set on my bucket, so after I did that everything went smooth.